# Solving problem using recursive functions

Tags: recursion, code-review, number-theory, education

Attached below is a question posed by the Canadian Mathematical Society, and I have my code and answer. Is there a better way of writing the code, and will the answer be different as a result?
[image]

My code and possible answer (edited):

```
jk[0] = 0; 
jk[1] = 0; 
jk[2] = 1; 
jk[3] = 2; 
tr[n_] := If[n > 3, 
  LengthWhile[Range[3, 20], Divisible[n, #1] & ] + 3, jk[n]]
Sum[tr[tr[tr[m]]], {m, 1, 2006}]

(* 2672 *)
```

Let me know if you get an answer that differs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a few mistakes. `jk[0]` should be 0 in your code and your function `tr` is wrong.

Corrected version:

```
t[0] = 0;
t[1] = 0;
t[2] = 1;
t[n_] := t[n] = LengthWhile[Range[1, 11], Divisible[n, #1] &] + 1
Sum[Nest[t, m, 3], {m, 1, 2006}]
```

> 1171

10x faster version:

```
t[n_] := t[n] = Module[{i = 1}, While[MemberQ[Divisors[n], i], i++]; i];
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure your summing is done properly -- compare `Total[t[#] & /@ Range[2006]]` which sums up all the t[i] value from 1 to 2006. The total is 5584

Comment: @paw -- thanks for the explanation. I'll erase my erroneous comment in a few minutes...

Answer (score 2):

```
f[0] := 0
f[1] := 0
f[2] := 1
f[x_] := Module[{j = 1}, While[Mod[x, j] == 0, j++]; j];
bt[x_] := Nest[f, x, 3]
Total[bt /@ Range[2006]]
```

yields 1171

Comment: Just as good. Thks